# Writing Pyspark in AWS Glue and trying to read and write data using Dynamo DB with DAX clusters

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I am able to read and write data into Dynamo DB tables by AWS Glue using Pyspark code through --->dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=region, endpoint_url=url)
I also want to use DAX clusters for faster execution.
Can someone suggest me how to use amazon-dax-client or any other approach to connect to the DAX clusters.

**OR**
Q->Does AWS Glue support Amazaon dax??

Answer (score 1):

This feature is still not supported from AWS Glue as confirmed by AWS support